# 'Here definetly' when editing floats doesn't work in APA v7 class

Tags: floats

So there i think MWE is. I cut out almost every piece od text that was there bc i didn't think it was relevant and I tried to make it MWE shorter. If sth is not right just let me know and I will try to provide. Also hen I changed documentclass to standard there was no problem with 'here definetly' function.

```
\documentclass[polish,man]{apa7}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Diagnoza osobowo�ci}

\affiliation{Wydzia� Nauk Spo�ecznych, Uniwersytet �l�ski, 21.12.2023}
\shorttitle{$ $}
\author{Miko�aj Krysik}
\maketitle

\subsection{1. Wywiad i opis sytuacji badanej}


\subsection{2. Analiza wynik�w}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[bb=1.35cm 6cm 22.575cm 18.375cm,clip,scale=0.6]{\string"wyniki 2\string".eps}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{APAitemize}
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{APAitemize}

\subsubsection{Para czynnik�w (N-,E-)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide code for a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Where can I find this code?

Comment: @MikołajKrysik You have to create this code, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/3225#3225 for some helpful tips

Comment: Please help us understand what you are doing and provide some code example. Currently all we can do is guessing what you do. In order to produce a helpful answer, we need to know about the packages you use and the document setup. Please add this information, preferably by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), to your question.

Comment: I really wish people wouldn't vote to close new users' questions before they even have a chance to respond to comments. It's not inline with policy outlined on TeX SE's Meta, however aligned it may be with SE's standard hostility. (And TeX SE doesn't *need* to do this. Unlike some other SE sites, we're not inundated with questions.)

Comment: @MikołajKrysik Even though the question has been so precipitously closed, you can still edit it and, once you've added the code, we can get it reopened (relatively) quickly, though it can take a few hours depending on who's around. Take no notice of the unsympathetic reception. Some users forget just how intimidating question closure can be for new contributors and how few tools those users have to understand and respond to what's happened.

Comment: Thanks for advice I will try to provide the best MWE I can. But I still dont understand some things listed in the link you sent. Hope you can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

The `man` class option will force figures to the end of the document. If you want them to behave like floats, you can use the `floatsintext` option.

Some other observations:

- Please also note that `\centering` is a macro and not an environment. Maybe you mixed it up with the `center` environment? (in your use-case, you should use `\centering` to avoid the extra vertical space from the `center` environment)
- I would avoid using `[H]` whenever possible. This often forces latex to place the image at an unsuitable place. Better use `[htbp]` to give latex as much room as possible to create a nice page layout for you.

---

```
\documentclass[polish,man,floatsintext]{apa7}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Diagnoza osobowo�ci}

\affiliation{Wydzia� Nauk Spo�ecznych, Uniwersytet �l�ski, 21.12.2023}
\shorttitle{$ $}
\author{Miko�aj Krysik}
\maketitle

\subsection{1. Wywiad i opis sytuacji badanej}
\subsection{2. Analiza wynik�w}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
%\begin{centering}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
%\par\end{centering}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{APAitemize}
\item
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{APAitemize}

\subsubsection{Para czynnik�w (N-,E-)}

\end{document}
```